# How to force-rebuild a package in Bazel to measure build time

Tags: bazel

I am currently trying to measure the time `bazel build //api/...` takes to build our "api" project with different `--spawn_strategy`s.
I am having a hard time doing so because Bazel doesn't rebuild anything as long as I don't touch the source files.

I was able to force rebuilds by editing all files inside our "api" project, but doing this repeatedly is cumbersome.

What is the best way to force Bazel to rebuild so that I can measure build times for our repository?

Preferably, I would like to use something like `bazel build //api/... --some_option_which_forces_rebuilding` or something similar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A bit dirty, but you could use [`--action_env`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--action_env) to change the build environment and invalidate all the actions. From [the docs](https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html#new-flag---action_env):

> Environment variables are considered an essential part of an action. In other words, an action is expected to produce a different output, if the environment it is invoked in differs; in particular, a previously cached value cannot be taken if the effective environment changes.

also (from [this page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html#when-is-the-implementation-function-executed)):

> [...] The value of those environment variable can be enforced from the command line with the --action_env flag (but this flag will invalidate every action of the build).

Just setting a random variable should be enough:

```py
> bazel build --action_env="avariable=1" :mytarget
> bazel build --action_env="avariable=2" :mytarget
> ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is already much better than my current approach.
However, I would like to keep the cache for everything else, except for `//api/...`.
(Many other dependencies in the dependency tree for which I would like to keep the cache)
Is there a way to let `--action_env` only influence parts of my dependency tree?

Comment: You could try using `config_setting` in `//api` with different values of the env variable for the different settings, see https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/configurable-attributes.html

Comment: I've decided to use the following flavor to generally get a rebuild ;) `--action_env=SHIT=$(date -Ins)`

Answer (score 2):

If you delete all the stuff in the output directory for the `api` package and its subpackages (should be under the `bazel-bin` symlink), bazel will rerun all the actions that produced those things, and not run any actions that produced things in other packages. This should also avoid rerunning the analysis phase, which changing `config_setting`s or `--action_env` will do.